# Android espresso :How to handle scenarios where click on a button launches external apps

Tags: android, android-espresso

In my app I have certain buttons which launches facebook, google maps, phone calling keypad, etc.

I just want to verify if it landed on maps/phone key pad opens/facebook app opens

Once I land on the external app there is no way to verify if i am on facebook/google maps etc and I am unable to go back to my app to continue further testing. 
Can someone help me with an example for this?

Thanks for taking time to go through my question.Would appreciate the help here.

Answer (score 0):

On espresso you should use espresso intents, this way you can detect the launch of external intents:
https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/

If you need more you should check UIAutomator.